# Get Values of multiple input fields from within parent element AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Firstly apologies if this has been asked before, but I have the following HTML which is generated dynamically by an angular directive (I.E When the user clicks a button, a new element is added to the page), all these entries are within a container div.

```
<div class="entry"><tr><td><input type="text" name="firstname"/></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="surname"  /></td></tr></div>
```

Once the user submits, I want to be able to get the data from both the inputs  within each entry.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thank You!

Comment: if you can give the directive code. or create a plnkr it'll be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested that you use ng-model and ng-submit in the directive.

```
<script>
    angular.module('MyApp', []).directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            template: '<form ng-submit="submit()">' +
                    '<div class="entry">' +
                        '<tr>' +
                            '<td><input type="text" ng-model="firstname" /></td>' +
                            '<td><input type="text" ng-model="surname" /></td>' +
                            '<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</form>',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                scope.submit = function() {
                    console.log("scope.firstname", scope.firstname);
                    console.log("scope.surname", scope.surname);
                };
            }
        };
    });
</script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```

Then, you can do anything else in the submit function with firstname and surname.

Comment: If you wanna use $compile, just tell me

Comment: Thanks for the help :)